# How to use flask-socketio for heartbeat detection

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

How to use flask-socketio for heartbeat detection.

The current requirement is to create an interface. When the client connects to the corresponding interface, the server periodically sends a message to the client, the client response a message to server, it proves that the client is alive, heartbeat detection.
I have tried to write the code using flask-socketio and it runs successfully, but I don't know how to test the multiplayer connection.If the connection is broken, I don't know how the thread stops.

```
class MyCustomNamespace(Namespace):
    clients = []
    def on_connect(self):
        sid = request.sid
        print('client connected websocket: {}'.format(sid))
        self.clients.append(sid)
        global thread
        with thread_lock:
            if thread is None:
                thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=self.background_thread, args=(current_app._get_current_object()))

    def on_disconnect(self):
        sid = request.sid
        print('close websocket: {}'.format(sid))
        self.clients.remove(sid)

    def on_message(self, data):
        print('received message: ' + data["param"])
        if data["param"] is not None:
            print('websocket {} is alive'.format(request.sid))
        # else:
        #     print('websocket {} is die'.format(*rooms()))
        #     self.disconnect(*rooms())


    def background_thread(self, app):
        with app.app_context():
            while True:
                time.sleep(6)
                data = {"status": "ok"}
                socketio.emit('server_detect', data, namespace='/testnamespace', broadcast=True)
                print("服务器探测客户端是否还活着")

socketio.on_namespace(MyCustomNamespace("/testnamespace"))
```

html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    namespace = '/testnamespace';
    webSocketUrl = location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace;
    console.log(webSocketUrl);
    var socket = io.connect(webSocketUrl);
    socket.on('server_detect', function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        socket.emit('message',{'param':'value'});
    });
});
```

Comment: It isn't necessary for your application to do this, as the Socket.IO protocol already implements a similar technique. The clients and the server are constantly exchanging ping/pong packets, so they already detect when one of the sides disconnects, and in that case the `disconnect` handler is invoked.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, and I saw the example of the source code.It has the ability to calculate the reception and transmission time of the heartbeat packet.In the process, it sends a ping packet using Javascript, and the pong package from server.It means that it is only for detecting the ping/pong packet time, so this part of the code is written. If you do not need to calculate this time, the code is not writtrn, the client and the server are also detecting.right?

Comment: The example that you saw uses events named ping and pong, but that is not what I meant. The Socket.IO protocol does this internally, regardless of what your application sends. Even if the connection is dormant with none of the sides sending data, the ping/pong mechanism of the protocol ensures the two sides remain connected.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you for your explanation.